# Equivalent openCV code for the imagemagick "convert -auto-gamma auto-level -normalize" command?

Tags: opencv, imagemagick

How can the equivalent of imagemagick's

```
convert -auto-gamma auto-level -normalize a.png b.png
```

be done in openCV?

Comment: From https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php: _`-auto-gamma`: Automagically adjust gamma level of image._ or _`-auto-level`: Automagically adjust color levels of image._ I'm afraid, you need to see the source code to rework the _automagic_.

Comment: @HansHirse Is there some sort of best approximation in terms of openCV?

Comment: I don't think so, since most OpenCV methods don't do things _automagically_, you have to specify what you want.

Comment: See skimage.exposure.rescale_intensity()